# SQL Query for Zip Code Error Message

Tags: error-messages, sql

I am trying to create a sql query for all database contacts within a certain number of miles of a zip code.  I keep getting an error message saying there was a syntax error near the word 'code'.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT CAST(
city, zip code, ROUND(6378.137 * ACOS(     
CASE       
  WHEN (SIN(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513))) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.Latitude))) + (COS(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513))) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Longitude) - RADIANS((SELECT longitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513)))) > 1 THEN 1       
  WHEN (SIN(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513))) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.Latitude))) + (COS(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513))) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Longitude) - RADIANS((SELECT longitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513)))) < -1 THEN -1       
  ELSE (SIN(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513))) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.Latitude))) + (COS(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513))) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Longitude) - RADIANS((SELECT longitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513)))) END),0) AS Distance 
  FROM   
  [Zip Code] AS geo 
  WHERE   
  ROUND(6378.137 * ACOS(     
  CASE       
  WHEN (SIN(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513))) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.Latitude))) + (COS(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513))) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Longitude) - RADIANS((SELECT longitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513)))) > 1 THEN 1       
  WHEN (SIN(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513))) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.Latitude))) + (COS(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513))) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Longitude) - RADIANS((SELECT longitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513)))) < -1 THEN -1         
  ELSE (SIN(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513))) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.Latitude))) + (COS(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513))) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Longitude) - RADIANS((SELECT longitude FROM [Zip Code] where Zip Code = 76513)))) END),0) <= 80)
```

Comment: what is the api name of your zip code field?

Comment: It is zip code.

Answer (score 0):

The Zip Code field in your select and where statement doesn't look like it has the delimited identifier. You probably need to wrap the field name in [] or ''

```
SELECT CAST(
city, [zip code], ROUND(6378.137 * ACOS(     
CASE       
  WHEN (SIN(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513))) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.Latitude))) + (COS(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513))) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Longitude) - RADIANS((SELECT longitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513)))) > 1 THEN 1       
  WHEN (SIN(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513))) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.Latitude))) + (COS(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513))) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Longitude) - RADIANS((SELECT longitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513)))) < -1 THEN -1       
  ELSE (SIN(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513))) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.Latitude))) + (COS(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513))) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Longitude) - RADIANS((SELECT longitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513)))) END),0) AS Distance 
  FROM   
  [Zip Code] AS geo 
  WHERE   
  ROUND(6378.137 * ACOS(     
  CASE       
  WHEN (SIN(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513))) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.Latitude))) + (COS(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513))) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Longitude) - RADIANS((SELECT longitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513)))) > 1 THEN 1       
  WHEN (SIN(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513))) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.Latitude))) + (COS(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513))) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Longitude) - RADIANS((SELECT longitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513)))) < -1 THEN -1         
  ELSE (SIN(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513))) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.Latitude))) + (COS(RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513))) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.Longitude) - RADIANS((SELECT longitude FROM [Zip Code] where [Zip Code] = 76513)))) END),0) <= 80)
```

Comment: Hmm. When I try that, it says there's a syntax error near " , "

Comment: maybe you can update your post with what you have tried so far other than the original query, try removing the comma after zip code as well.